# How to execute SQL query in a new database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core-2.2

My problem is like this... I'm creating a software where you have different areas of a business and those areas have a property name ConnectionString.

So when the administrator of the system wants to know certain specific information of the area all he does is register a SQL query.

My problem is in the logic of how to do execute the query. I'm creating a new DbContext and pass the connection string but I can't find a function of DbContext to run the query.

Does someone know any function of DbContext to run a query and get the result?

Comment: you can execute query using `FromSql()` method of `DbContext` https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/raw-sql-queries-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: I have just seen that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you require to execute raw query in Entity Framework Core using `DbContext` object you can access like

For access raw query

```
var students = context.Students
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Students Where id = 1")
    .ToList();
```

If your requirement is access or get data from a stored procedure:

```
var students = context.Students
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetTopperStudents")
    .ToList();
```

if passing with parameter then

```
var name = new SqlParameter("name", "abc");   
var students = context.Students
            .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetTopperStudents @name",name )
            .ToList();
```

if execute command insert/update/delete then

```
 var commandText = "INSERT Students (name) VALUES (@name)";
    var name = new SqlParameter("@name", "Test");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
```

if you are execute query or stored procedure in not your model or you add custom model then you can execute as query like

my studentFees Model is not any model related to database.

```
public class StudentFees
{
      public int StudentId { get; set; }
      public string StudentName { get; set; }
      public decimal Fees { get; set; }
      public DateTime FeesDate { get; set; }
}
```

and just add your query into your `DbContext` `OnModelCreating()` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Query<StudentFees>();
}
```

now if you can access and execute your query or your stored procedure in custom model

```
var studentId = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@studentId", 1);
        var studentsFees = _dbContext.Query<StudentFees>.FromSql("GetStudentFees @studentId", studentId).ToList();
```

in this way you can access or set your custom model also and execute query or stored procedure.

Let me know require more information.

Comment: In the many options you give me you know the DbSet, but in my project i will not know the DbSet. What i only know is the connection string from a database and the query to impact in that database, so i don't know the DbSet. Can you help me with that?

Comment: you are used entity framework core righr ?  Then your  implementation of `DbContext` contains DbSet

Comment: Yes but the query I have to execute it is not for my model

Comment: @DanielAcevedo i have just edit my answer you can also execute query or store procedure if its not in your model, just require to add in your `DbContext` method. let me know require more information